# Iteration through a std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

[image]

Why is it asking me to overload the operator = ? 
I have previously iterated through a std::list and I did not have such problems.

```
class Grup : public Shape {

private:

    std::vector<Shape*> continut;

public:

    static const std::string identifier;

    Grup();
    ~Grup();

    void add(Shape *shape);
    void remove(Shape *shape);
    void output(std::ostream &outs) const;
    void readFrom(std::istream &ins);
    void moveBy(int x, int y);

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &outs, const Grup &grup);
};


std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &outs, const Grup &grup)
{

 std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it;

    outs << "Grupul este format din: " << std::endl;

    for (it = continut.begin(); it != continut.end(); it++)
    {

    }    

    return outs;
}
```

Error: "No viable overload '='. "

Comment: Please print the code, screenshot is not clear enough and how is `Grup` defined??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(After magnification of the screenshot) `grup` is being passed in as a `const`, so [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) will return a `const_iterator` which cannot be assigned to an `iterator`.

Change declaration of `it` to:

```
std::vector<Shape*>::const_iterator it;
```

---

Note In C++11 you can use `auto` to instruct the compiler to deduce the type:

```
for (auto it = grup.continut.begin(); it != grup.continut.end(); it++)
{
    outs << **s << std::endl;
}
```

Other alternatives in C++11 are the [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& shape: grub.continut)
{
    outs << *s << std::endl;
}
```

or [`std::for_each()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
std::for_each(grub.continut.begin(),
              grub.continut.end(),
              [&](Shape* s) { outs << *s << std::endl; });
```

Comment: @Teodora, it depends if there is an overload for `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Shape&)`. In the first `for` the `iterator` needs dereference to access the `Shape*` and then `Shape*` needs dereferenced.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
std::vector<Shape *>::iterator it;
```

to:

```
std::vector<Shape *>::const_iterator it;
                      ^^^^^^
```

As you are passing in a `const Grup` reference.

Or if you are using C++11:

```
for (auto it = grup.continut.begin(); it != grup.continut.end(); ++it)
{
     ...
}
```